# Как обрезать число long в java?

Tags: java

Как обрезать число long в java, не преобразовывая long к String и после этого не используя метод substring?

Например:

Есть число `12345`, из которого нужно получить только `12`.

Comment: Обрезать? Число? Приведите пример.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://ideone.com/9It3vG

```
long x = (1L << 48) | (1L << 16);
int y = (int)x;
System.out.println(x + " " + y);
```

> Есть число 12345, из которого нужно получить только 12.

http://ideone.com/OMLRp9

```
long x = 12345;
long y = x / 1000;
System.out.println(x + " " + y);
```

Comment: Я пробовал, но не получилось. Мне нужно из System.currentTimeMillis получить секунды.

Answer (score 3):

Разделить на 10^n, где n - количество убираемых символов.

```
long i = 30304033;
int n = 5; //убрать 5 символов
i /= (long) Math.pow(10,n);
```

Comment: Точно не надо Math.pow к чему-то целочисленному кастить? А то как-то не джавоподобно выглядит...

Comment: Теперь джавоподобно)

Comment: Если надо из миллисекунд получить секунды просто разделите на 1000 и все.

Comment: Минус был не мой. Кстати, наверное лучше long, а не int.

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
long PowerOfTen(int n)
{
    long result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        result *= 10;
    return result;
}

int n = 123456;
// отбросить последние три цифры
n /= PowerOfTen(3); // --> n == 123
// оставить только последние две
n %= PowerOfTen(2); // --> n == 23
```

Для проверки переполнения, возможно, лучше использовать [`Math.multiplyExact`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#multiplyExact-int-int-).

---

Возможно, у вас XY Problem. Если всё, что вам надо, это количество секунд с начала Unix Epoch, используйте

```
LocalDateTime.now().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toEpochSecond()
```

Comment: _"только первые две"_ - последние же?

Comment: @Qwertiy: Точно! Спасибо, исправил.